# Checking a string for a sequence of letters and numbers using values from a list (Python)

Tags: python

I'm stuck on searching a string for a particular sequence of numbers and letters. I need to be able to search a string (a car reg numberplate) for the sequence of **two letters, two numbers and then three letters**. So far, I have this:

```
if any(letters in carReg for letters in letters): # Good enough
    print("")
    valid+=1
    if any(numbers in carReg for numbers in numbers): # Good enough
        valid+=1

if valid==0:
    print("Invalid license plate.")
elif valid==1:
    print("Does not contain both numbers AND letters")
elif valid==2:
    print("Valid License Plate")
```

where `letters` and `numbers` are just lists:

```
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
```

which are declared at the start of the program.

The code above works, but only if the string entered is composed entirely of letters, or entirely of numbers. It doesn't check for a sequence, as the program needs to do.

**Edit**: carReg is given by this line:

```
carReg = input("Please enter your licence plate: ")
carReg = carReg.upper()
```

Comment: carReg is given by an input in which the user can just enter a license plate.

Comment: Looking for strings that have a particular form is exactly what regex's do. Unfortunately I'm not particularly good with Python's regex syntax, so wait a bit and someone will give you the regex and, hopefully, a good explanation of what it does.

Comment: This really sounds like a use-case for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). If the string matches e.g. `r"[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}"` then you're done, unless misunderstanding something.

Comment: @unwind This seems like it would work, but how would I substitute my code into this? Would the A-Za-z bit be replaced with "letters" (the list), for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reg = "ab11foo"

a,b,c = reg[:2],reg[2:4],reg[4:] # slice string into ll nn lll
# check a is all alpha characters, b is made up of 0123456789 and c is again alpha and length is correct
if all((a.isalpha(), b.isdigit(), c.isalpha(), len(c)== 3)):
       print("Valid reg")
else:
     print("Invalid reg")
```

You could also use sets and [set.issuperset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
letters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}
numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"}
a,b,c = reg[:2], reg[2:4],reg[4:]

if all((letters.issuperset(a), numbers.issuperset(b), letters.issuperset(c), len(c)==3 )):
    .....
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  yes, best answer. next time I will use this method. :)  Thank you and Up vote

Answer (score 2):

You test is wrong, since you don't take order and count of letters/digits into account. This sounds like the right work for a regex:

```
import re

if re.match(r"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}$", carReg):
    print("Valid :)")
else:
    print("Invalid :(")
```

the pattern means *"two letters in A-Z or a-z, then 2 digits 0-9 and other 3 letters in A-Z or a-z"* and the `^$` part means that the string must have that exact format, with no extra trailing or leading parts.

Comment: Regular expression is also one way to solve this problem. one up vote,  but length of string is not validated when greater then 7 .

Answer (score 0):

Use normal `if` condition:

1. Get User input by `raw_input()` method.
2. Convert to Upper case by string `upper()` method.
3. Check length of user input by `len()` method.
4. Check character sequence according to problem definition.

e.g.

```
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

carReg = raw_input("Please enter your licence plate: ")
carReg = carReg.upper()
if len(carReg)==7:
    if carReg[0] in letters and carReg[1] in letters and carReg[2] in numbers and\
    carReg[3] in numbers and carReg[4] in letters and carReg[5] in letters and\
    carReg[6] in letters:
        print "Valid licence"
    else:
        print "Wrong licence"

else:
    print "Wrong licence"
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 
Please enter your licence plate: aa123fgr
Wrong licence
$ python test.py 
Please enter your licence plate: ss12fgr             
Valid licence
$ python test.py 
Please enter your licence plate: adw
Wrong licence
$ python test.py 
Please enter your licence plate: 12asder
Wrong licence
```