# Regex on string to match sequence of characters

Tags: python, regex

**Set-up**

I have a large set of product images, of which some have the product's SKU in the file name.

I need to check if the file name contains the product's SKU.

All SKUs consist of 5 numbers, an underscore and 2 numbers; e.g. `'10008_01'`, `'23521_18'`, etc.

---

**My code**

I'm using the regex set-up I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673877/7326714):

```
for image in product_image_list:

    if re.match(r"^[0-9]{5}$" + '_' + r"^[0-9]{2}$", image):
        print('Match: '+ image)
    else:
        print("NO match: " + image)
```

where,

- `image` is the image file's name, e.g. `'FINAL 10008_01_angle.jpeg'` or `'FINAL 10008_detail_B.jpeg'`, etc.
- `product_image_list` is the list containing the images.

---

**Problem**

The above code doesn't match, it produces `'No match'` only.

How do I get it to work properly? I.e. how do I get:

`'Match: FINAL 10008_01_angle.jpeg'`

`'No match: FINAL 10008_detail_B.jpeg'`

Comment: The SKU names are part of the strings, right? Try `if re.search(r'(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{2}(?!\d)', image):`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you're the man. So if it's inside a string, I need to `re.search` not `re.match`?

Comment: Yes. Now, the question is, if you have `FINAL 2310008_0231_angle.jpeg`, do you want it to be returned as a match?

Comment: No. I don't want that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^[0-9]{5}$_^[0-9]{2}$` pattern will never match any string since the `$` anchor inside requires the end of string, but there are more chars to match (`_`, then start of string, 2 digits and again an end of string).

You need to fix the regex pattern to match a `<5-digit>-<2-digit>` substring with no enclosing digits and use the pattern with a `re.search` method (since `re.match` only searches for the match at the start of the string):

```
if re.search(r'(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{2}(?!\d)', image):
```

Here,

- `(?<!\d)` - (a negative lookbehind) matches a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a digit
- `[0-9]{5}` - 5 digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` -  (a negative lookahead meaning) there must be no digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NfK7rz/1).

To print the matches use

```
for image in product_image_list:
    m = re.search(r'(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{2}(?!\d)', image)
    if m:
        print('Matched SKU: {}'.format(m.group()))
    else:
        print("NO match found in '{}'.".format(image))
```

To match multiple occurrences use `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{2}(?!\d)', image)
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's a bit out of the scope of the question, but could I also make it print the SKU if it's inside the name? So if `image='FINAL 10008_01_angle.jpeg'` that it would print `'10008_01'`?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I found that images with a file name similar to `'FINAL 77718_02.jpeg'` are not being matched. I suppose that is because of the `(?!\d)` negative lookahead?

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` looks for a complete string match, which is not what you want. Your regex is also more complicated than it needs to be. The below should work.

```
import re

product_image_list = [
  'FINAL 10008_01_angle.jpeg',
  'FINAL 10008_detail_B.jpeg'
]

for image in product_image_list:

    if re.search(r"[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{2}", image):
        print('Match: '+ image)
    else:
        print("NO match: " + image)
```